# Change version of documented code in doxygen (without using macros)

Tags: c++, documentation, versioning, doxygen

Is there any way to change the version in a comment block?

For e.g.

```
const char VER[] = "1.2.3.4";

/**
 * \version (VER)
 */
```

I know how to do this with preprocessing and I was wondering if there were any other way?

On a related note, how do you guys handle changing version numbers in documentation, the application, etc. without changing different version numbers all over the place? Right now I have a `VER`-like variable in a namespace accessible by all (essentially global without namespace pollution).

Comment: By code you mean, i think nope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most developers use a source control tool which usually provides a mechanism for obtaining the current revision, stringizing it, and inserting into the source.  Something along the lines of

```
const char *VER = "$Rev$";
```